# Smallest (sub-) Sigma algebra of a null set

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Given a probability space ($\Omega,\mathcal{A} ,P$) and $N \in \mathcal{A}, N \ne \emptyset$ with $P(N) = 0$

What is the smallest sub-sigma algebra of $\mathcal{A}$ containing $N$.

I'm kind of confused, would $\{\Omega, \emptyset, N, \bar{N} \}$ be the smallest? Or do I overlook something because $N$ is a null set?

And what would that imply for the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(X|\sigma_N)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Sigma algebras have nothing to do with the measures of sets in them. You're right, $\{\Omega,\emptyset,N,N^c\}$ is the smallest sigma algebra containing $N$. You can assign $N$ any measure you want, null or otherwise.

As far as conditional expectation goes. You have that $\mathbb{E}[X|\sigma_N]=a1_{N}+b1_{N^c}$. Can you solve for $a,b$?